# Netty HTTPS server using Comodo certificate

Tags: ssl, https, netty

I'm using Java 8, Netty 5 Alpha.

I added the certificates from Comodo to the keystore, and according to a test website suggested by my certificate provider they are installed correctly.

But if I try to connect using Firefox, Chrome, or curl, I get errors.

From `curl -v` I see that it gets the correct header, but then `SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):`. This seems to correspond with debug messages from Java:

```
SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 32

fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
```

Firefox: `SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.`

From `openssl s_client -connect ...`:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain

SSL handshake has read 5982 bytes and written 531 bytes
```

I've read elsewhere about NullPointerExceptions somewhere causing internal Java security stuff to fail. But there's no clear solutions.